# Machin reboots during istallation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

I've tried both versions now, 14.04.3 and 15.10 with the same result. No matter if I just choose to try without installation or install I'm stuck in a bootloop. Istantly after I choose one option the machine reboots.
I used Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.3 to create the bootable USB-Stick and chose to format the stick while doing so.
I'm running Windows 8.1 on an UEFI-System with an AMD CPU and a Radeon GPU.
I also tried disconnecting the SSD with the other OS (Win 8.1) and just leaving the HDD with no OS on it attached and even without any HDD attached, just the USB stick. Same result. I get stuck in a bootloop.
Somewhere in this forum I read that it helps hitting Tab, removing "quiet" and "splash" and instead typing "nomodeset xforcevesa". I tried and it helped a little bit. Now I see how the system is loading the two first files. After the second file is loaded it says ".....ready" but after that the machine immediately reboots.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Seems as if it was the Universal-USB-Installer's fault. Tried Unetbootin and it works now.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/521890)

Comment: @Weboide: this is the OP answering his own question.  For the future: leave the answer alone and close the question with "Off opic - unable to reproduce"  **;-)**